# jquery ui icons, hover not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to put a help icon from jquery ui next to a input field. I get a button with a question mark but no effect when I hoover over it.

```
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon ui-icon-help"></span>
```

Also, the questionmark is not yellow like is not yellow like it is in the demo. I have all the files.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post your code??

Comment: Without seeing the code you're actually using we'll have to resort to guessing. The color of the icons is determined by the jQuery UI theme you're using, and unless you have a CSS hover setup, the span you created won't change by itself.